# Putting a keyword into a string matrix (VB)

Tags: vb.net, string, matrix

How can I make a matrix with strings (5 by 5)?

E.g. I want something like this:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p r s t u
v w x y z
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What do you want to reach? Where is your problem in this? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use a 2 dimensional array if it's going to always have a static size (such as 5 by 5) though I wouldn't recommend them in any other situation you're using VB for since they really don't like to be adjusted.  Here's a decent explanation of arrays in vb http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/lesson6.html